# Debian php ffmpeg error "Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern"

Tags: php, ffmpeg, debian

My code below works fine in on my osx laptop

```
$sec = 1;
$ffmpeg = \FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create([
   'ffmpeg.binaries'  => exec('which ffmpeg'),
   'ffprobe.binaries' => exec('which ffprobe')
]);

$video = $ffmpeg->open($file);
$frame = $video->frame(TimeCode::fromSeconds($sec));
if(!file_exists($newFilePath)) {
      $frame->save($newFilePath);
      $this->output->writeln('make: ' . $newFilePath);
}
```

but on debian I get error `Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern`

here is the error description from ffmpeg website

> This usually occurs because the output name is incorrect or some option was omitted.
> If outputting a single image you need to include -frames:v 1.
> If outputting a series of images you need to use the proper naming pattern as described in the image muxer documentation. For example, output_%03d.png will make a series named output_001.png, output_002.png, output_003.png, etc.
> If outputting a single image that is continuously overwritten with new images, add -update 1.

My filename looks fine to me

here is the detailed error:

```
ffmpeg failed to execute command '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-ss' '00:00:01.00' '-i' '/var/www/web/public/data/post/J4ukGXDowqFFA6hNIuP11606468845/BuF8e7HrkX1606  
  468845.mov' '-vframes' '1' '-f' 'image2' '/var/www/web/public/data/post/J4ukGXDowqFFA6hNIuP11606468845/BuF8e7HrkX1606468845-preview.webp':

Error Output:

ffmpeg version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd
64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass
--enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libf
ribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-li
bpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-l
ibtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-li
bzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chrom
aprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/web/public/data/post/J4ukGXDowqFFA6hNIuP11606468845/BuF8e7HrkX1606468845.mov':                               
Metadata:
major_brand     : qt
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: qt
creation_time   : 2020-11-27T09:17:34.000000Z
Duration: 00:00:03.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 932 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 138 kb/s (default)                                                                 
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2020-11-27T09:17:34.000000Z
handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 480x264, 780 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)  
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2020-11-27T09:17:34.000000Z
handler_name    : Core Media Video
encoder         : H.264
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> webp (libwebp_anim))                                                                                                          
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, image2, to '/var/www/web/public/data/post/J4ukGXDowqFFA6hNIuP11606468845/BuF8e7HrkX1606468845-preview.webp':                                        
Metadata:
major_brand     : qt
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: qt
encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
Stream #0:0(und): Video: webp (libwebp_anim), yuv420p, 480x264, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)                                                
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2020-11-27T09:17:34.000000Z
handler_name    : Core Media Video
encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libwebp_anim
[image2 @ 0x55bc313ccfc0] Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern '/var/www/web/public/data/post/J4ukGXDowqFFA6hNIuP11606468845/BuF8e7HrkX16064688  
  45-preview.webp' (either set update or use a pattern like %03d within the filename pattern)                                                                           
  av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument                                                                                                                        
  frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.06 bitrate=N/A speed=1.54x                                                                                         
  video:18kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown                                                                       
  Conversion failed!
```